# Laravel inner join on two queries

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have a query where I'm joining two queries to get what I want, I can manage this just fine in SQL however I'm at a complete loss now as to how I'd write this for Laravel. Here's the SQL:

```
select *
from 
    (
        select stu.s_nid as student_nid, stu.name as student_name, vote.id as vote_id
        from student stu
        left join vote on vote.student_id = stu.id
        where vote.vote_no != 0
    ) as q1
    inner join 
    (
        select stu.s_nid as nominee_nid, stu.name as nominee_name, vnd.nominee_type_id, vnd.vote_id, nt.name_ar
        from vote_nominee_details vnd
        left join nominee nom
        on nom.id = vnd.nominee_id
        left join student stu
        on stu.id = nom.student_id
        left join vote
        on vote.id = vnd.vote_id
        left join nominee_type nt
            on nt.id = vnd.nominee_type_id
        where vnd.vote_id is not null
        and vote.vote_no != 0
    ) as q2 on q1.vote_id = q2.vote_id
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just try this

```
$result = DB::select($sql);
```

you can also try this

```
DB::table(DB::raw('(select stu.s_nid as student_nid, stu.name as student_name, vote.id as vote_id
        from student stu left join vote on vote.student_id = stu.id
        where vote.vote_no != 0) as q1'))
->join(DB::raw('(select stu.s_nid as nominee_nid, stu.name as nominee_name, vnd.nominee_type_id, vnd.vote_id, nt.name_ar from vote_nominee_details vnd 
        left join nominee nom on nom.id = vnd.nominee_id
        left join student stu on stu.id = nom.student_id
        left join vote on vote.id = vnd.vote_id
        left join nominee_type nt on nt.id = vnd.nominee_type_id
        where vnd.vote_id is not null and vote.vote_no != 0) as q2'), 'q2.vote_id', '=', 'q1.vote_id')
->get();
```

Comment: First solution worked perfectly, thank you so much! Second one produced an error that I didn't understand: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'as' (SQL: select * from `(select` as `as` inner join `(select` as `as` on `q2`.`vote_id` = `q1`.`vote_id`)

Comment: Bossman! Thanks so much for your help, can confirm both solutions work, I ended up using the second - not sure if one is superior to the other in any way?

Comment: they are the same, no difference. you can give me a up vote, thanks.

Comment: Sorry sir, I thought accepting the answer was enough. You have been upvoted! :)